# how to change y axis values in qqplot

Tags: r

This is my code. I have used ggplot2. I want to change axis values of y alone as mentioned in the pic below

```
library(ggplot2)
rm(list=ls())
bar=read.csv("Age.csv")
attach(bar)
Category=sub('\\s+$', '', Category)

HSI = HSI-100
df = data.frame(HSI=HSI,Category)
ggplot(df, aes(x=Category,y=HSI,  fill=Category)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(width=0.3)) + # adjust width to change thickness
  geom_text(aes(label=HSI+100, y=HSI+2*sign(HSI)),# adjust 1.1 -  to change how far away from the final point the label is
            size=5 # adjust the size of label text           
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you remove 100 from HSI, and then add 100 to geom_text ?
It should work as you want by keeping HSI at its original value.

Comment: @xraynaud Actually I want bar in the barplot should start from 100.  It show go down if HSI values are less than 100 and up vice versa ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `scale_y_continuous` to set the breaks and corresponding labels:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Category,y=HSI, fill=Category)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(width=0.3)) + # adjust width to change thickness
  geom_text(aes(label=HSI+100, y=HSI+2*sign(HSI)), size = 5) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-20, 30, 10), labels = 100 + seq(-20, 30, 10))
```

This will produce your desired graph (alongwith a warning message: *In loop_apply(n, do.ply) : Stacking not well defined when ymin != 0* which can be ignored in this case).

Comment: Is there any way to shift axis position to y=0 to y=100? so that i can avoid hsi=hsi-100 and then adding up later. @B.Shankar

Comment: @AbdulShiyas, It can be done I suppose, using coordinate transforms but it will unnecessarily complicate things.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to alter HSI. You just have to use ylim() ggplot function:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Category,y=HSI,  fill=Category)) + 
geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(width=0.3)) + 
geom_text(aes(label=HSI, y=HSI+2*sign(HSI)),
size=5)+
ylim(100,130)
```

EDIT: Above solution does not work for geom_bar.

The solution needs to define a translate function from the scales library.

```
library(scales)
translate100_trans <- function() {
  trans <- function(x) x - 100
  inv   <- function(x) x + 100
  trans_new("translate100_trans", trans, inv)
}

ggplot(df, aes(x=Category,y=HSI,  fill=Category)) + 
geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(width=0.3)) + 
geom_text(aes(label=HSI, y=HSI+2*sign(HSI)),
size=5)+scale_y_continuous(trans="translate100")
```

Comment: I don't think this would produce a useful result. Limiting the y-axis that doesn't include `0` will cause the bars to not show up at all. You can test this on `df <- data.frame(HSI = c(126, 104, 112, 94, 86), Category = factor(LETTERS[1:5]))`

Comment: Correct. This work for geom_point, not geom_bar. I've edited the answer for  a solution working with geom_bar.